# Combo box in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

```
<ComboBox x:Name="c1" Margin="21,134,228,-184" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="6" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFFF0017" />

List<String> source = new List<String>();

c1.ItemsSource = source;

c1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

I can see the items but I can't select them? and I can't scroll??? like when I add more than the size of the combo box,

it should appear a scroll? I'm coming from windows store c# and that is the way it is over there.

I want it to make it work just as a regular combobox, you click on it and it will appear a scrollable list of items that you can select... Thanks!

Comment: Try with this: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/129558/The-ComboBox-is-Dead-Long-Live-the-ListPicker

As far as I know ComboBox (or controls like that) isn't recommend in WP applications (it should be use only for small collections - for example about 3 items).

Answer (score 4):

It is not recommended to use combobox control. Use the ListPicker Control.

Steps :

1. Download the nuget package from this link: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPtoolkit/
2. Add a reference to the top of your xaml file :

   ```
   xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
   ```
3. Use ListPicker as shown below :

   ```
   <toolkit:ListPicker  Height="50" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ConverterPage, Path=Locations}" Margin="179,129,70,434" Name="cmbCurrFrom">
           <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBlock FontSize="30" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Path=Location}"></TextBlock>
               </DataTemplate>
           </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
           <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBlock FontSize="30" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Path=Location}"></TextBlock>
               </DataTemplate>
           </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
       </toolkit:ListPicker>
   ```