# IsEditable="true" not Showing in Combobox in windows phone 8.1?

Tags: search, combobox, windows-phone-8.1

I want to perform a search on a `combobox`. I use this code:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="rechargeOperator1"   
           BorderBrush="#FFABAABF" 
           Margin="10,80,10,0" 
           Height="44" 
           BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" 
           VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           PlaceholderText="Select Operator"
           RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"  
           Background="Black" >
</ComboBox>
```

I googled that I need to use "IsEditable="True" on the Combobox but i'm not getting `IsEditable="true"` option on the combobox in the Xaml file.

please anyone help me to do this

Comment: Iam getting The property "IsEditable" does not have an accessible setter." error

Answer (score 1):

`ComboBox.IsEditable` always returns false for a Windows phone app and it cannot be modified. Reference - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox.iseditable.aspx

This property is available only for WPF application. For Windows phone its recommended to use listpicker - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/129558/The-ComboBox-is-Dead-Long-Live-the-ListPicker

Answer (score 0):

Actually `ComboBox.IsEditable` is read only Property You cannot set the value for that.For windows Phone [Combobox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox.iseditable.ASPx) is here.

You can try `AutoSuggestBox` in wp8.1 for that you need to add Like this in `Xaml`

```
<AutoSuggestBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"  TextChanged="AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged"/>
```

in code Behind

```
private void AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        List<string> myList = new List<string>();
        foreach (string myString in PreviouslyDefinedStringArray)
        {
            if (myString.Contains(sender.Text) == true)
            {
                myList.Add(myString);
            }
        }
        sender.ItemsSource = myList;
    }
```

Try this this will work for you.

Comment: @BhargaviReddy if you are creating silverLight wp8.1 means you can use WPtoolkit if you are using WinRT wp8.1 you need change your combobox like this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2d2d83/combobox-in-windows-phone-8-1/

Comment: which control are used replace to combobox.I want to replace combobox

Comment: @BhargaviReddy check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256075/combo-box-in-windows-phone-8  and its applicable for silverlight projects only

Comment: in my combobox many items are there.how to search required item .please tell me sample code

Comment: Actually I am not using silverlight.